# How to know user is coming into app by using of Universal links

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I using Universal linking in my application.

When the user pick on link directly move into root view controller.

But I want to change the rootviewcontroller when user entering through Universal link.

please help to those delegates methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 delegate method that will fire when application is open from link or user tap link as per below.

**Swift**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // handler for URL Scheme "This will called for URL schema"
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // handler for Universal Links "This will called for Universal Link"
    return true
}
```

Comment: hello pinkish in wich method I write the root view controller changing code.

Comment: Second method. "continue"

Comment: First is for URL schema only For Universal Link you have to use second method

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```